# Flutter: setState not updating value

Tags: flutter

In my code the setState is not updating the value that show in the Dropdownbutton, I already try two configurations, as I had read that this has something to do with the build process of the widget, but none of the two methods works

Code 1

```
class InteriorDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const InteriorDropdownButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InteriorDropdownButtonState createState() => _InteriorDropdownButtonState();
}

class _InteriorDropdownButtonState extends State<InteriorDropdownButton> {
  final interiorTypeList = [
    'Cuero',
    'Foamizada',
    'Vinilo',
    'Tela',
    'Microfibra'
  ];

  String? selectedInterior;

  DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
    for (String interiorType in interiorTypeList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(
          interiorType,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        value: interiorType,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }

    return DropdownButton<String>(
        items: dropdownItems,
        value: selectedInterior,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.expand_more_outlined),
        iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
        isExpanded: true,
        hint: const Text('Tapiceria'),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .025,
        ),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedInterior = value;
          });
          print('Hola ${selectedInterior}');
          print('Hello ${value}');
        });
  }

  CupertinoPicker iOSPicker() {
    List<Text> pickerItems = [];
    for (String interiorType in interiorTypeList) {
      pickerItems.add(Text(interiorType));
    }

    return CupertinoPicker(
      diameterRatio: 1,
      itemExtent: 32.0,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
        setState(() {
          selectedInterior = interiorTypeList[selectedIndex];
        });
      },
      children: pickerItems,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return androidDropdown();
  }
}
```

Code 2

```
class MoldsDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoldsDropdownButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MoldsDropdownButtonState createState() => _MoldsDropdownButtonState();
}

class _MoldsDropdownButtonState extends State<MoldsDropdownButton> {
  String? dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final moldsTypeList = [
      'Madera/Cromo/Plastico',
      'Madera/Plastico',
      'Plastico'
    ];
    DropdownButton<String> androidDropdown() {
      List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
      for (String moldsType in moldsTypeList) {
        var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(moldsType),
          value: moldsType,
        );
        dropdownItems.add(newItem);
      }
      return DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          items: dropdownItems,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.expand_more_outlined),
          iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: const Text('Molduras'),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .025,
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = value;
            });
          });
    }

    CupertinoPicker iOSPicker() {
      List<Text> pickerItems = [];
      for (String interiorType in moldsTypeList) {
        pickerItems.add(Text(interiorType));
      }

      return CupertinoPicker(
        diameterRatio: 1,
        itemExtent: 32.0,
        onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = moldsTypeList[selectedIndex];
          });
        },
        children: pickerItems,
      );
    }

    return androidDropdown();
  }
}
```

the console prints are:
flutter: Hola null
flutter: Hello Foamizada

The value is updated, but the selectedInterior prints null

Comment: It is working fine here, can you try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: did you solved the error?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I clean and rebuild and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

both are working fine... use **flutter clean** or restart the code editor and emulator.

Comment: I just didn't I it doesn't work